# SQL using WHERE with comma values

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, codeigniter, where-clause

I have product_id column which has data `30ed1476c6d04337b02f783079c2290f, a3b14b2d2603499393cde6bf120a059e` in `TEXT` datatype. I combied the 2 product id and save it to db using implode. Now my problem is how to get the data using 1 product id.

For example `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE product_id = 30ed1476c6d04337b02f783079c2290f`

Comment: use `like` instead of `where`

Comment: Comma lists in mysql fields aren't something to search on. Look up normalization before you got too far with this structure.

Comment: this looks like bad database design, read about [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE product_id like '%30ed1476c6d04337b02f783079c2290f%'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first effort should go into fixing your data model; you should have a separate mapping table, where each value would be stored in a separate row. Storing csv data in a relational table is the root of many evils. See: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/10676716)

That said, for your current schema, you can use [string function `find_in_set()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
select *
from table1
where find_in_set('30ed1476c6d04337b02f783079c2290f', product_id)
```